# Prevent elements from wrapping when resizing the window

Tags: html, css

How can I prevent my squares from wrapping when resizing the window?

I want the squares to stay at their positions, but every time I resize the window, they get pushed down and are hidden.

This example is currently working, but the solution, which makes this possible, is just ridiculous.

Is there a "cleaner" way or how can I make it look more professional?

[My JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/643yL/3/)

```
.content {
    width: 100000000px;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` and `overflow:hidden` from the parent element.

Since the elements are `inline-block`, you could use `white-space:nowrap` to prevent them from wrapping. If that's not the desired effect, just remove it though.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/CLErY/)

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution but white-space has no support for float elements.

Comment: @MarcosEusebi Right - they have to be `inline` elements.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CLErY/2/

```
/* The following rule can be romoved, is just to give a smooth overflow hidden visibility */
.content {
    width: 200%; /* Always bigger than the real value, so 200% is the double and it should work. */
}
```

.content should have at least the size of the whole element plus the size of one children (100px), so 200% is the double and it should work.

In case we have 4 squares the size should be (width x 4 + width) in case the width of the square is 100 the result is 500px.

Also this is to give a smoother overflow dissapear but not necesary.

Hope it helps.